# Intellij / Android Studio Split Screen

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Does Intellij / Android Studio have a split screen option similar to this in vim?

[image]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

1. Open the context menu on a document tab by right-clicking on it.
2. Select **Split Vertically**.

   [image]
3. You will now have two columns to place document tabs into:

   [image]

### Hotkey

If you want to assign a hotkey to the action, do the following:

1. Open the **Settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).
2. Search for **Split Vertically** (or *Split Horizontally*, if that's what you're after) and select the **Keymap** in the IDE Settings.

   [image]
3. Open the context menu for the action in question and select **Add Keyboard Shortcut**.
4. Assign the desired hotkey. In this example, I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>:

   [image]
5. Here we can see the result of assigning a hotkey to both the vertical and horizontal split action:

   [image]

Comment: How do you do this from hotkey?

Comment: @DavidT.: I've added instructions to the answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: works! thanks so much!! oh, and step 1 -> on the mac, the settings hotkey is actually CMD + ,   (but that's something most mac users already know, so it's fine as is :)

Comment: @DavidT.: Feel free to edit the answer to show the hotkey version for the Mac :)

Comment: Thanks Oliver! Do you know the key shortcut to jump between the split windows?

Comment: @okysabeni I click Ctrl + Tab to switch between the two split windows!

Comment: @lukle I think I re-assigned my `ctrl + tab` keys.  Where do I find the command in the settings?  In other words, what word should I search for in the keymap?

Comment: It's "switcher"

Comment: They should add this under the [ View ] menu.

Comment: still works for AS v3.5